# Show posts in random order from category loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a category loop in Wordpress that outputs different markup based on the category. This is all fine, now I need the posts to display in random order. I've used 'orderby => "rand" but this only randomises the posts within each category, i.e. the categories themselves are still outputted in chronological order. I'm unsure what to do and would appreciate any help.

Code:

```
<?php

$categories = get_categories();
  foreach($categories as $category) {
  $args=array(
  'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
  'caller_get_posts'=>1,
  'orderby' => 'rand'
);
$posts=get_posts($args);
  shuffle($posts);
  if ($posts) {
    foreach($posts as $post) {
      setup_postdata($post); 
                   echo "<li class='cat-{$category->term_id}'><a href='".get_permalink()."'>".get_the_post_thumbnail()."</a></li><!-- 
                   -->";

    } 
  } 
} 
?>
```

Update: Resolved withiEmanuele's advice - adding shuffle( $categories );

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `shuffle( $array );` to shuffle elements in array.

```
$categories = get_categories();
shuffle( $categories );

foreach( $categories as $category ){
    //Your stuff
}
```

Hope it helps!